# Do I need to install any libraries or SDKs to use OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I am wondering if I have to install libraries for openGL programming or if I can already use header files from the core library. I am asking this because I went to the SDK and there is no Core library for OpenGL development. There is however a few libraries to choose from. I am new to this.. If you could please help clarify the subject for me that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will need a library and headers to use OpenGL.

Fortunately, every major operating system ships with the libraries and headers already in place for you, so you do not need to download and install anything from the OpenGL website itself in most cases.

However, especially on Windows, you may want to download and install the latest drivers for your video card as they will generally improve the OpenGL functionality made available to you through the OS-supplied libraries.

Comment: I'd add that on Windows you need to load almost every OpenGL function by something like `wglGetProcAddress`, so it's useful to use a wrapper libary like `gl3w`. The library and headers already in place are super old and incomplete

Comment: I am not familiar with wglGetProcAddress